# Download CSV button

Tags: php, angularjs, csv

I have a list of users and I want to export it as a CSV file. I binded the button to an Angular controller.

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary-icon" href="" ng-click="csv()">Download CSV</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.csv = function() {
        $scope.export.cols = _.keys(_.pick($scope.data.columns, function(col) {
            return parseInt(col.checked) === 1;
        }));

        $http({
            url: $scope.dataUrl,
            data: $.param({
                export: 1,
                csv: $scope.export
            }),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('ErrorOnResponse', data);

            if (data.csv) {
                Download.download(
                    'yarooms-report-' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.csv',
                    'application/csv',
                    data.csv
                );

                Analytics.log(Analytics.event.EXPORT, Analytics.category.REPORTING);
            }
        });
    };
```

My problem occurs when it comes to writing the PHP function that grabs the data from my DB. I even tried to export a simple hardcoded array, but it won't work.  When I click the button, it makes a request to the server, but that's all, no downloaded file, nothing.

My testing PHP function:

```
$file = 'php://memory'
$list = array (
                array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
                array('123', '456', '789'),
                array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
            );
$f = fopen($file, 'rw+');
foreach ($list as $fields) {
     fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }
rewind($f);
$csv = stream_get_contents($f);

fclose($f);

Support_Model_Entity::logStat('Exported users CSV');

$this->jsonResponse(array(
    'csv' => $csv
));
```

Comment: what err does it print?you can see it in the console

Comment: It doesn't print anything in the console.

Comment: In developer tools for your browser, what are the details of the request and response. If it makes a request to the server, there will be some kind of a response. Your call to `$http` has no catch/error case. Without that error case it will appear to do nothing in the case of an error.